# How to draw formal sums of trees?

Tags: graphs, trees

I would like to draw something like this:

[image]

in a way that, as in the picture, the + sign is centered with respect to the height of the trees. so far I used the tabular environment but the result is unsatisfying, I get something like this:

[image]

Any idea?
Thank you in advance!

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\forestset{solid nodes/.style={for tree={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black}},
            dir/.style={for tree={grow=#1}},
            leaf/.style={label=$#1$},
            mytree/.style={solid nodes, for tree={grow=north,s sep=1cm}}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{c c c } 
        \begin{forest} mytree
        [
        [,leaf=r_1] 
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(2)}] [,leaf=x]
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(1)}][,leaf=r_2]
        ]
        ]]]
        \end{forest} 
    &
    +
    &
        \begin{forest} mytree
        [
        [,leaf=r_1] 
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(2)}] [,leaf=x]
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(1)}][,leaf=r_2]
        ]
        ]]]
    \end{forest} 
    \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you ˆpst the code you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative that doesn't involve modifying the trees themselves is to use the `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\forestset{solid nodes/.style={for tree={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black}},
            dir/.style={for tree={grow=#1}},
            leaf/.style={label=$#1$},
            mytree/.style={solid nodes, for tree={grow=north,s sep=1cm}}}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{
        \begin{forest} mytree
        [
        [,leaf=r_1] 
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(2)}] [,leaf=x]
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(1)}][,leaf=r_2]
        ]
        ]]]
        \end{forest}
}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{
   $+$
 }
\adjustbox{valign=c}{
        \begin{forest} mytree
        [
        [,leaf=r_1] 
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(2)}] [,leaf=x]
        [
        [,leaf=x^{(1)}][,leaf=r_2]
        ]
        ]]]
    \end{forest} 
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3):

You need to write option `baseline` to nodes, which you like to be aligned with sign `+`:

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\forestset{solid nodes/.style={for tree={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black}},
            dir/.style={for tree={grow=#1}},
            leaf/.style={label=$#1$},
            mytree/.style={solid nodes, for tree={grow=north,s sep=1cm}}}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
 \[
        \begin{forest} mytree
        [
            [,leaf=r_1]
            [
                [,leaf=x^{(2)}, baseline]   % <---
                [,leaf=x]
                [
                    [,leaf=x^{(1)}]
                    [,leaf=r_2]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        \end{forest}
       +
        \begin{forest} mytree
        [
            [,leaf=r_1]
            [
                [,leaf=x^{(2)}, baseline]   % <---
                [,leaf=x]
                [
                    [,```leaf=x^{(1)}]
                    [,leaf=r_2]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        \end{forest}
 \]
\end{document}
````

[image]